# Reload page, If there are more than three div

Tags: javascript

I have a page where circles are created and appear in random places.

When you click on the circle, it hides.

I want to make it so that when there are more than 3 circles on the page at the same time, then alerts appear, and when you click on ok, the page reloads.

I tried to add this piece to the end of the code, but nothing works:

```
if(i > 3) {
  alert('Alert For your User!');
  window.location.reload(); 
}
```

```js
//create circle

var widthHeight = 35;
var margin = 25;
var delta = widthHeight + margin;

let clicks = 0;

function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  var currentTop = 0;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  div.setAttribute('class', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.borderColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.borderColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  div.classList.add("animation");
  
  currentTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentHeight) - delta;
  currentLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentWidth) - delta;
  
  var limitedTop = Math.max(margin * -1, currentTop);
  var limitedLeft = Math.max(margin * -1, currentLeft);

  div.style.top = limitedTop + "px";
  div.style.left = limitedLeft + "px";
  
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.animation');
  for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear';
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.animation = '';
    }, 220);  });
  }
  
  $(div).click(function() {
    $('#clicks').text(++clicks);
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
  
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
let i = 0;

const oneSecond = 600;

setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, oneSecond);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like a cool game. Instead of using `i` since you use it elsewhere, create a global called `circleCount` then increment when a circle is drawn and decrement when a circle is clicked. Then place your condition for determining game win inside your click handler after you decrement.

Comment: @GetSet did everything as you said, but it does not stop automatically, until you click, the alert will not drop out

Comment: There may be a conflict with the alert tying up the ui thread and your setInterval. Consider using a non-blocking way to display the message. Or, make sure you clear the interval.

Comment: @GetSet 
If the conditions are placed immediately after the clicker, then everything is as it should be, only after clicking OK, garbage happens

Comment: Well the advice I gave solved your immediate problem. Now you have the rest of the problems to solve. Can you clarify and elaborate what you mean by "not drop out" and "garbage happens"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable circleCnt. When creating a new circle, assign +1, when clicking -1.

You can then do your own validation with this variable.

```js
//create circle

var widthHeight = 35;
var margin = 25;
var delta = widthHeight + margin;

let clicks = 0;
let circleCnt = 0;

function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  var currentTop = 0;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  div.setAttribute('class', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.borderColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.borderColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  div.classList.add("animation");
  
  currentTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentHeight) - delta;
  currentLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentWidth) - delta;
  
  var limitedTop = Math.max(margin * -1, currentTop);
  var limitedLeft = Math.max(margin * -1, currentLeft);

  div.style.top = limitedTop + "px";
  div.style.left = limitedLeft + "px";
  
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.animation');
  for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear';
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.animation = '';
    }, 220);  });
  }
  
  $(div).click(function() {
    --circleCnt;
    $('#clicks').text(++clicks);
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
  
  if(circleCnt > 3) {
    alert('Alert For your User!');
    window.location.reload(); 
  }
  
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
let i = 0;

const oneSecond = 600;

setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  ++circleCnt;
  createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, oneSecond);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```